# How to get multiple fields from a dropdown box in php to be used in other programs

Tags: php, jquery

I have two drop down list in the main page, when the user clicks on the country drop down(on change) another drop down list would be shown with the product list. This I accomplish using an ajax call (**getproduts.php**) from the country drop down list. The screen shots, the ajax call and the programs are attached .

The dropdown list works well and I can select the item too. The drop down list has the both the product description and the price in it.

I would like to get the price in a variable to be used in the main program when ever the user selects the option.

The sub total value(attached screen) in the main program  should change with the price from the dropdown box when ever the user selects the product.
How can I achieve this?.

```
Ajax call

<script type="text/javascript">
function get_products()`enter code here`
    { 
           var country = $("#country").val();
    var type = $("#type").val();
    var dataString = 'country='+ country + '&type=' + type;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",`enter code here`
        url: "getproducts.php",  
        data: dataString,
        success: function(html)
        {
        $("#get_products").html(html);
        }
    });
}

</script>


getproducts.php

<?php
error_reporting(1);
//print_r($_POST);
include('function/db_connect.php');
//session_start(); 
$price = Null;
//$items = Null;
if($_POST)
{
$var1 = $_POST['country'];
$var2 = $_POST['type'];
 if ($var1 != '') {         
       echo "<label>Item<span style='color:red'>*</span></label><span style='color:red'></span></label><span class='address'>";
       echo "<select id='items' name='items' style = 'width: 546px;' onChange='get_price(this.value)'>";          
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE country_id = '$var1' AND type_id = '$var2'";   
       $db  = new DB_CONNECT();    
       $result = mysql_query($sql); 
       $myarray = array();
       echo "<option value=''>Select</option>"; 
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $idp = $row["product_id"];
            $iddes = $row["product_desc"];
            $selp = $row["product_sell"];
            $costp = $row["product_cost"];


       echo "<option value='" . $idp . "'>" . $iddes . "==>".$selp ."</option>";

       }
       echo "</select><label>Item</label></span><span class='address'>";

    }   
       echo "</div>";         
       echo "<br>";     



       echo "<div><label></label><span class='name'><button name = 'data'  type ='button' onclick= 'valprice('items')'>Validate value</button></span></div>";      

    }
?>
```

Comment: where is your `get_price` function?

Comment: It is to get the price of the product selected,i have used this as an alternative as I do not know how to select multiple fields from the same table and store in some variable and use it in the main program when the user selects the prducts

Comment: Can some one help me?

Comment: What you mean by `select multiple fields from the same table and store in some variable`? did't get it

Comment: The table product has product code, description, selling price, cost price and the category. When I select the product , I should be able to select  the selling price also along with the product  that is what I meant by multiple fields. Currently I can select only the product(items). Hope this clarifies your query.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I still have issues, can't get the price .  Your demo shows Array [ Object ] it does not show the value.

Comment: I can send you the screen shot if you can provide the e-mail address,as I can't attach screen short for lack of credits.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Ghazali, it works fine now .  Once again thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear that! You're welcome

Answer (score 0):

Right now in your select html element, you're using `onChange='get_price(this.value)`, this line of code only get the option value in this case only `$idp = $row["product_id"];`. If you want to select others field, then you need to attach those values into option itself during looping process occured. Here is the example usage.

In your option tag, change into this :

```
echo "<option value='" . $idp . "' data-price='" . $selp . "'>" . $iddes . "==>".$selp ."</option>";
```

You see i adding `data-price='" . $selp . "'` as a user defined attribute. This later on we fetch at `onchange` event.

After that, change your select HTML element onchange into this :

```
echo "<select id='items' name='items' style = 'width: 546px;' onChange='get_price(this)'>";
```

Finally, in your `get_price()` function tweak into this below code :

```
<script>
// array variable to store product details[id and price in this case]
var myProduct = [];
function getPrice(e) {
  // set to empty for initial
  myProduct.length = 0;
  // fetch price
  var price = $('option:selected', $(e)).data('price');
  // fetch val ID
  var valID = $(e).val();

  // insert into array variable as a javascript object
  myProduct.push({
    ID : valID,
    price : price
  });

  console.log(myProduct);

}
</script>
```

To fetch another fields, put another `data-attributes` like example above.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/teeLfh5d/)** - check console to see the output